# Behaviour of Address space layout randomization (ASLR) when entropy is low

Tags: encryption, linux-kernel, cryptography, entropy, aslr

As per <[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170334/reading-entropy-avail-file-appears-to-consume-entropy)> question, a process (like cat) reads in entropy from random pool for Address space randomization (ASLR).

To check ASLR behavior I depleted the entropy manually as given below

- 1) cat /dev/random to deplete all available entropy.
- 2) cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail to check available entropy.

The second cat process didn't block, even though the entropy is just depleted fully. So it appears ASLR  seems to be working fine (?) even though entropy was not sufficient.

My question is **what is the expected behavior of ASLR when entropy is really low ?** Since it dont have random bit to read from /dev/random, will it use some other algorithm to generate entropy internally ?

Comment: I'd assume that it uses the equivalent of `/dev/urandom`.